# Companion to Böhm-Jacopini

Tags: programming-languages

The [Böhm-Jacopini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem) states that any 'unstructured' program can be rewritten in structured way. There is a companion theorem that states that in this structuring process the tests that are performed may not be the same as the original.

Does anyone have a reference for this other theorem?

Comment: The question originally stated that you were looking for a "converse" theorem but the description you give isn't that of a converse. I edited to change the term but feel free to undo that if you really are looking for a converse (in which case, you should describe why it is a converse, too).

Comment: Sure its not a converse but somewhat 'converseish'. So your edit is ok. A bigger help would be to tag the question with something better than 'programming-languages